# Is an immersion an embedding almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $F \colon M \to N$ be a smooth immersion. I know that $F$ is a local embedding, but is it also an embedding *almost everywhere*?

In other words, does there exists a set of measure zero $X \subset M$ such that $F$ restricted to $M \setminus X$ is a smooth embedding?

Comment: To those who voted to close: could you kindly share some input on how to improve the question?

Comment: Can only guess, but it is really nothing more than a problem statement question (PSQ), no better than someone writing the preamble of a question in a Calc I text, then asking what the exercise asks of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No: a covering map of smooth manifolds is an immersion but (I'm nearly sure) never has this property unless it is a diffeomorphism.

For example, map $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$ to itself by $z\mapsto z^2$. This is an immersion but a measurable subset $T$ of the domain on which the map is injective has measure at most $\frac{1}{2}$ the measure of $S^1$, because if $A:S^1\to S^1$ is the antipode ($A(z)=-z$) then $T\cap A(T) = \emptyset$, so that $\lambda(T) + \lambda(A(T)) \le \lambda(S^1)$, where $\lambda$ is the length measure on $S^1$; but $\lambda(T)=\lambda(A(T))$, since $A$ is an isometry.

Answer (score 13):

In case it's of interest, even an *injective* immersion can fail everywhere to be an embedding. An irrational winding on a torus is an example: Fix an irrational number $\alpha$. The path $\gamma(t) = (t, \alpha t)$ in the real plane descends to an injective regular path on the square torus $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^{2}$ whose image is dense.

Comment: I don't see how density implies nonzero measure. The set of rational numbers is dense in the reals, but has measure zero.

Comment: @Acccumulation You're right that density does not imply positive measure, but that's not the issue here: The image of the reals ($M$) is dense in the torus ($N$), so the irrational winding fails to be an embedding at every real number (i.e., $X = M$ is the entire domain).